# use the button on the slick that doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slick.js

I use slick, if javascript **dots: false** then the button to display the picture frame appears if js **dots: true** is activated, the button to display the picture frame doesn't work, why?

here I want dots: true, and the button to display the image works fine

---

This is to display an image when clicking on a button:

```
<div id="picture-frame">
    <div id="pic">
       <img id="gambar" class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

when clicking the image button appears in the img frame :

```
<div class="mysliderS">
    <button id="gambar-t" data-img="data-img="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'"">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'" alt="Image">
    </button>
    <button id="gambar-t" data-img="data-img="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'"">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'" alt="Image">
    </button>
    <button id="gambar-t" data-img="data-img="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'"">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'" alt="Image">
    </button>
    <button id="gambar-t" data-img="data-img="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'"">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'" alt="Image">
    </button>
    <button id="gambar-t" data-img="data-img="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'"">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/produk/'.$gambar'" alt="Image">
    </button>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#gambar-t',function(){
            var gm_src = $(this).attr('data-img');
            console.log(gm_src);
            $('#gambar').attr('src',gm_src);
            $('#picture-frame').find('img').attr('src',gm_src);
        });
    });

    $('.mysliderS').slick({
          dots: true,
          infinite: false,
          slidesToShow: 7,
          slidesToScroll: 7,
          responsive: [
          {
              breakpoint: 1100,
              settings: {
              slidesToShow: 5,
              slidesToScroll: 5
              }
          },
          ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this `data-img="data-img="` typo in the question posted or in actual code?

Comment: Your HTML should only contain one element per ID, but you have multiple `id="gambar-t"` buttons. You should convert the IDs to class and then use `$( ".gambar-t" ).click();` to select them.

Comment: thanks for the help, it turns out that the error uses ID